# cuda convnet equvilent method from opencv gpu::convolve

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, cuda, convolution

I've used Opencv's [gpu::convolve](http://code.google.com/p/cuda-convnet/) for convolution on CUDA. I see that  [cuda convnet](http://code.google.com/p/cuda-convnet/) does convolution too. Anyone know how to call cuda convnet from c++ to get a similar logic like OpenCv's gpu::convolve? I want to compare which implementation is faster running convolution on the CUDA especially when running a batch of filters on an image.

Comment: convnet is convolutional neural network it is (rather complicated and powerful) unsupervised learning tool. Convolution operation (in image processing) is just simple weighted summing of neighbour pixels values.

Comment: Andrey, convnet has several parts and it is complicated as you noted. Code is not heavily documented so one must read over the code. It does convolution on images when it trains so I'm wondering if there is a method in there that does something like opencv's gpu::convolve.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use cuda sample located (on my machine) in folder:
c:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v5.5\3_Imaging\convolutionSeparable\

And here is description paper: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_64_website/projects/convolutionSeparable/doc/convolutionSeparable.pdf

Comment: +1. That is very helpful. Does convnet use that in it's implementation to get the "best" performance out of it?

Comment: I don't think that convnet uses separable convolution because not all kernels are separable, but convolutional networks need convolution with arbitrary kernel (which it computes by training). I think it uses implementation of 2D convolution.